# Is it possible to manage Azure AD B2C applications via APIs?

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

is it possible to manage apps and services from Azure AD B2C via APIs (REST etc.) for individual users?
The authorised AD applications should be managed later in a self-developed dashboard via APIs.)

Best regards

Comment: Azure AD B2C directories do not have an azure subscription to host apps and services. Be more specific on exactly what you want to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Using the rest API, you can manage All the App services and also Azure resources.

for example [updating the Api service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceenvironments/createorupdate)

```
 PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/{name}?api-version=2019-08-01
```

API for App service Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/) it may help